# Mysql Data for month and year

Tags: php, mysql, datepicker

I have a datepicker where the selected date will post the data by day, month, and year. I have the "by day" working, but can't seem to get the month and year to click... here is the code that works for the day.

```
    <?php  
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d"); 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","xxxxxxxxxx");  
if (!$con)  {  
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());  
}  
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con);  

$sql = "SELECT sum(power) AS choice FROM feed WHERE date = '".$choice."'"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
echo $row['choice'].'<br />';  
?>
```

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood what you want to do, but if you want to display data for a given month, the following sql query should work:

```
$sql = 'SELECT . . . WHERE month(date) = [month picked] AND year(date) = [year picked]';
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: an inline datepicker on the webpage can select a a single calendar date... that date will post the PHP file and the data for the sum values (sum hour totals for day as seen above) will then show in a div (one dive for each value day, month, and year. The code above works doe the sum of values for a selected day, now I need the php for the month total the selected date, and the year total of that selected day

Comment: I would separate the month and the year from de selected date, doing something like this: explode('-',$choice);

Comment: Yes... I forgot to do that for the year... working smooth, thanks